# Windows::UI::Popups::MessageDialog stopped working

Tags: uwp, messagebox

I had this code, and it worked fine:

```
if(auto dialog=ref new Windows::UI::Popups::MessageDialog(ref new Platform::String(L"title"), ref new Platform::String(L"error"))) 
      {
         //dialog->Commands->Append(ref new Windows::UI::Popups::UICommand("OK", ref new Windows::UI::Popups::UICommandInvokedHandler(this, &Exiter::onOK)));
         dialog->ShowAsync();
      }
```

But ever since I've updated the Windows to latest Creators Update, and my Visual Studio 2015 to 2017 and latest Windows UWP SDK, then this code doesn't work anymore. Nothing happens, no message box is displayed anymore.
Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in latest Windows UWP SDK?

Comment: Have you tried your code in a new Blank App project? I tested it with a new Visual C++ Blank App (Universal Windows) project and it worked well. I'm targeting **10.0.15063.0** and my OS Build is 15063.250.

Comment: For now I can only tell that I'm using a DirectX-based app, and I'm using 10.0.14393.0 SDK (this is the only option available in my VS 2017), and no message box is displayed.
I'll try to get the 10.0.15063.0 SDK and try again.

Comment: updating the SDK fixed the message box problem, but now it caused a different one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858973/include-iphlpapi-h-fails-on-latest-windows-uwp-10-0-15063-0-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating VS 2017, and using latest 10.0.15063.0 SDK, the problem went away.